# How do I handle res.download(pathname) on frontend(ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I have written a code on my server(NodeJS) that will send a .csv file to the frontend with express res.download(path). I would like to know how I can handle the response with fetch API that will allow the frontend to download the file(.csv) sent.

I am using reactJs on my frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the [downloadJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) on my frontend

```
import download from 'downloadjs'
...
//get request
fetch(url).then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => download(blob, 'name of file', 'data type')) // this line automatically starts a download operation
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hello @octagod, thank you for your answer, please what do I place in the 'data type' ?

Comment: @jsninja you can read more on the downloadJS package from the link in my answer.

Comment: So sorry, the 'data type' should be 'text/plain' in your case since you are dealing with a csv file

Comment: I will try it out and see if it works